# Unable to script users

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I'm logged in as sa on my local SQL Server 14.0.1000.169 database and I'm trying to run the following script:

```
 CREATE USER [myuser] FOR LOGIN [myuser] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
 GO
```

I get the following result:

```
Msg 15007, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
myuser is not a valid login or you do not have permission
```

I double-checked and `myuser` doesn't exist and `dbo` does exist, any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a user for SQL Server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13123682/create-a-user-for-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 0):

**Before Creating a User you must first create a global Login.**

`under Security -> Logins -> NewLogin`

Or

First connect to the server and switch to the master database. In master create a login and then add a user for that login to the master database.

```
CREATE LOGIN [MyLogin] WITH password='xxxxxxxxx'
GO

CREATE USER [MyUser] FOR LOGIN [MyLogin] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo] 
GO
```

> Once the login exists you can add them as a User under a particular
> database.